# In Flutter How I can update screen with updated records automatically by click on delete button

Tags: flutter, dart

Following is the widget, it doesn't update the screen with updated records on clicking the delete button. How I can update the screen with changed list by clicking the delete button. It updates only when I refresh.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<UsersCubit>(
      create: (context) => UsersCubit()..getUsers(),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("All Users List"),
        ),
        body: BlocBuilder<UsersCubit, List<UserModel>?>(
          builder: (context, allUsers) {
            if (allUsers!.isEmpty) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: allUsers.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(allUsers[index].name),
                      trailing: IconButton(
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.delete_forever),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              _dataService.deleteUser(allUsers[index].id);
                              BlocProvider.of<UsersCubit>(context).getUsers();
                            });
                          }),
                    ),
                  );
                });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Use statefulWidget?

Comment: Yes, i used stateful widget ,

Comment: Hi Muhamad :) Can you clarify whether Kozubi's comment was helpful? Did it solve your issue?

Comment: try using a TabBarView instead and create a method that returns a widget